# JestJS - show all uncovered lines in coverage report

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

When I run the Jest coverage report, it prints out each type of coverage and the percentage by file. The last column that shows the uncovered lines gets truncated when there are more than ~4-5 lines. Is there a way to print all of the uncovered lines?

```
-------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File                           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
-------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files                      |    75.57 |    69.18 |    74.21 |    75.83 |                |
 js/components/catalyst        |    80.74 |    72.97 |    80.16 |    81.85 |                |
  JobGroup.jsx                 |    57.14 |       50 |    44.44 |       60 |... 33,34,38,73 |
...etc
```

This shows me that JobGroup.jsx has lines 33,34,38, and 73, but there are more, and I'd like to see them all at once.

Comment: Looks like an hardcoded setting in istanbul. The only workaround I found is to look at the report in the browser from the file `<coveragedir>/lcov-report/index.html`

Comment: @stilllife, I couldn't quite find the file that you suggested, but that did prompt me to check the `cobertura-coverage.xml` report that we have, and that does have what I need (with some digging)! Thanks! If anyone else is reading this in the future and has a `cobertura-coverage.xml` file, the lines that have `hits="0"` are the uncovered lines.

Comment: I bet there's a better way. Lab.js for instance outputs a nice html coverage report with hit count per line iirc

Answer (score 35):

> Is there a way to print all of the uncovered lines?

I'm using React + TypeScript + Jest. In my project, I run `npm test -- --coverage`, and the file with the remaining uncovered lines is under the `coverage` directory:

```
<project name>\<directory>\<directory>\coverage\lcov-report\index.html
```

(Your file path may have a variation on the `coverage` part. :-))

Then I navigate to the file of interest:

[image: code coverage results for file of interest]

All lines highlighted in pink are uncovered:

[image: line highlighted in pink]

Comment: This works great! The only *nit* I would add is that currently, as long as you're using an up-to-date version of Yarn (1.0 and above), you don't need the extra `--` in the CLI command. It can simply be `npm test --coverage`

Answer (score 11):

**This is an alternative solution that some may find helpful.**

Personally, I use VSCode, and there is a plugin available called "Code Coverage", it does something similar to the other answer here, by Super Jade, except it will highlight the code after you run a coverage test, like so.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Impressive ! Thank a lot